# Auto Login Hook in Liferay

Tags: liferay, autologin

I have written a hook ( class extending from `AutoLogin`) which gets called when any request is being made.
In the login method of my class, I have a logic to authenticate the request parameters sent with the request.

Now If the authentication is cleared, I check if the user exists in liferay using

```java
UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByScreenName(companyId, username)
```

Now if the user does not exist in liferay, I add a user to the liferay

```java
user = UserLocalServiceUtil.createUser(contactId);

user.setFirstName(fname);
user.setLastName(lname);
user.setActive(true);
user.setAgreedToTermsOfUse(true);
user.setCreateDate(new Date());
user.setScreenName(username);
user.setCompanyId(companyId);
user.setPassword("test");
user = UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser(user);
```

Now here I see the user getting created .
However sometimes it gives the following exception

```
com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

Any idea why this could be occuring?
Also if the user creation is successful when I login to the portal as admin, this user is not listed in the list of users.
Any idea why this is happening? Am I going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using the wrong method to add user. Check editUserAction.java under enterprise-admin portlet source for more details.